# Can a bind variable be concatenated to a dynamic SQL WHERE clause in order to add an AND statement?

Tags: oracle, where-clause, dynamic-sql, bind-variables

I am attempting to add an `AND` statement to a dynamic `WHERE` clause using a bind variable and I am receiving the following Oracle error:

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string bind variable

Here is the offending code:

```
FUNCTION WhereClause RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    where_sql := 'WHERE TRUNC( ' || parm_rec.SRC_DATE_COLUMN || ' ) < ADD_MONTHS( ' ||
                                  'ADD_MONTHS ( TRUNC (  NVL ( :SYS_OFFSET, SYSDATE ) - ( :DAY_OFFSET )), ' ||
                                  '( :MON_OFFSET * :kNEGATIVE ) ), ' ||
                                  '( :YR_OFFSET * ( :kANNUM * :kNEGATIVE ) ) ) ';

    RETURN where_sql;
END WhereClause;



PROCEDURE ArchiveSrcDateFilter
IS     
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ArchiveDynamic - ENTER');
IF parm_rec.SRC_DATE_COLUMN IS NULL THEN parm_rec.SRC_DATE_COLUMN := 'NULL';
END IF;
    FOR i in tbl_cur
    LOOP
    where_sql := WhereClause; -- defines the WHERE clause (where_sql) via function, Spec will not return variable to body?
    /*** DYNAMIC SQL DECLARATIONS ***/
        arc_sql := 'DECLARE ' ||
                    /*** DYNAMIC %ROWTYPE SELECT ***/
                        'CURSOR arc_cur IS ' ||
                        'SELECT * '||
                        'FROM '  || i.ARC_TABLE_NAME || '; '||               --obtain ARCHIVE ARC_SCHEMA_NAME.ARC_TABLE_NAME
                        'TYPE arc_cur_type IS TABLE OF arc_cur%ROWTYPE; ' || -- dynamically set archive record cursor %ROWTYPE for BULK COLECT as table collection 
                        'arc_rec    arc_cur_type; ' ||                       -- define archive record as TABLE OF cursor.%ROWTYPE          

                    /*** ARCHIVE PARAMETERS CURSOR - SRC_CREATE_DATE IS NOT NULL***/
                        'CURSOR parm_cur IS '||
                        'SELECT :seq_val AS ARCHIVE_ID, '||
                        'A.*, ' ||
                        'SYSDATE AS ARCHIVE_DATE ' ||
                        'FROM ' || srcSchemaTable || ' A ' ||                -- archive SRC_SCHEMA_NAME.SRC_TABLE_NAME (source table not archive table)
                        where_sql || ' || :ADD_FILTER ' || ' ; ' ||

               /*** DYNAMIC SQL STATEMENT BODY ***/                   
                   'BEGIN '||
                        'IF parm_cur%ISOPEN THEN CLOSE parm_cur; ' ||
                        'END IF; ' ||
                        'OPEN parm_cur; ' ||
                        'LOOP ' ||
                            'FETCH parm_cur ' ||
                            'BULK COLLECT INTO arc_rec LIMIT 500; ' ||
                            'EXIT WHEN arc_rec.COUNT = 0; ' ||
                            'FORALL i IN 1..arc_rec.COUNT ' ||
                                'INSERT INTO ' || arcTable ||
                                ' VALUES arc_rec( i );' ||
                                'DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ''ARC_REC_COUNT: '' || arc_rec.COUNT ); ' ||
                        'END LOOP; ' ||
                        'CLOSE parm_cur; ' ||                                   
                        'DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''SUCCESS...''); '||
                    'END; ';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ArchiveDynamic - INSIDE LOOP: ' || arc_sql );

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE arc_sql
        USING seq_val, parm_rec.SYS_OFFSET, parm_rec.DAY_OFFSET, parm_rec.MON_OFFSET, kNEGATIVE, parm_rec.YR_OFFSET, kANNUM, parm_rec.ADD_FILTER;

    END LOOP;

END ArchiveSrcDateFilter;
```

This is the specific piece of code in the ArchiveSrcFilter procedure where the `:ADD_FILTER` bind variable is located (*Note: I have attempted different concatenation iterations for the bind variable without success this was simply my last attempt before posting the issue here*) :

```
'CURSOR parm_cur IS '||
'SELECT :seq_val AS ARCHIVE_ID, '||
'A.*, ' ||
'SYSDATE AS ARCHIVE_DATE ' ||
'FROM ' || srcSchemaTable || ' A ' ||
where_sql || ' || :ADD_FILTER ' || ' ; ' ||
```

And the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE USING with the last parameter as the bind:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE arc_sql
USING seq_val, parm_rec.SYS_OFFSET, parm_rec.DAY_OFFSET, parm_rec.MON_OFFSET, kNEGATIVE, parm_rec.YR_OFFSET, kANNUM, parm_rec.ADD_FILTER;
```

the `parm_rec.ADD_FILTER` = `AND STATUS = 1062`

Is it possible to do what I am attempting by concatenating the bind to the where?

I don't understand the odd error message I am receiving given that the code executes without exception if I concatenate the `parm_rec.ADD_FILTER` object variable or hard code the `AND STATUS = 1062`.

I can concatenate the `parm_rec.ADD_FILTER` in place of the bind variable and the code executes without exception, but I have been unsuccessful in attempts to get the bind variable to work.

I'm grateful for any suggestions and/or insight.

Thanks!

Comment: That part --  where_sql || ' || :ADD_FILTER ' || ' ; ' || -- makes no sense at all. You are applying string concatenation || to a logical condition. This cannot work. Nevertheless, the error you get looks unrelated to this.

Comment: You would think it is unrelated,  but it does only occur when I attempt to use the bind variable in the manner that I am. Which consensus between yourself and @Allen below so far have stated it is not the correct use, nor possible.  Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Column names (i.e. `STATUS`) and operators (i.e. `AND`, `=`) can never be resolved from bind variables.

Comment: Is the use of the object variable `parm_rec.ADD_FILTER` subject to SQL injection?  This package likely will not interact with an external web page or be subject to external use; however, I am curious if SQL injection is a potential issue in this instance? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Any time you concatenate together a SQL statement you are at risk for SQL injection. You need to determine, based where your application is getting the values that are used to construct the SQL the extent of the risk. `DBMS_ASSERT` can be used to further mitigate the risk for object and column names, but there is no built in validation for appending comparisons.

Comment: Any concatenation? Anywhere there are double pipes? I'm not concerned about SQL injection in this particular program it's internal use only and will be behind multiple layers of security without a non-IT  presentation layer (e.g., DB development/management tool). I suppose I just don't know enough about the mechanics of SQL injection. Hi-ho off to research I go! Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @TheSchnitz Using concatenation within a query is fine (i.e `select 'x' || some_column from table`). Using it to construct the query is a potential vulnerability (i.e. `execute immediate 'select ' || column_name || ' from table'`).